# android: aapt.exe has encountered an error

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I created a ids.xml file in res/values folder . when I tried to add any id in it . I got the following error:

```
aapt.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.
```

and when i clean and build project.i again got this error. any suggestion..?

Update: when i m creating ids.xml file, eclipse create this file without having any error. but when i m trying to add something i gives me crash.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="auto_focus" />
</resources>
```

when i added auto_focus i got the error

Comment: I am not able to create ids.xml file.when i create i got this aapt.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem.Check out all your .xml files and make sure nothing wrong with them.

Answer (score 3):

It happens to me when I delete not needed string resource
    name="action_settings"

Just write it back and everything was fine

Answer (score 0):

Do You have verbose output enabled in Your `Preferences>Android>Build>Build Output`?

If so, please change it to `Normal`. Probably it is the issue.

Comment: i did the same but again getting same problem.

Comment: Running `Project>Clean` didn't help either? Can You send logs before this crash? Maybe some other resources are incorrect?

Comment: if i clean the project , it does not generate R.java file.

Comment: And do You have something logged on console before that? If turning off verbose mode doesn't help turn it on again and provide us logs :)

Comment: i exaclty dont know what the problem is.

Comment: We also don't know. Until You provide some logs We can't help you, because We have no clue what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me once, when i added a existing file to my project named pin-1.png. then I renamed my file to pin1.png, and thats solves my problem.